# Bayesian estimation of iid sample from Uniform$[0,\theta]$ and a Pareto$(\alpha,\beta)$ prior for $\theta$

Tags: bayesian, estimation, uniform-distribution, conjugate-prior

I am working on Bayesian estimation: suppose that $X_1,\dots, X_n$ is an iid sample from Uniform$[0,\theta]$. Assume a Pareto prior for $\theta\sim Pareto(\alpha,\beta)$, i.e.
$$
f(\theta)=\frac{\alpha\beta^\alpha}{\theta^{\alpha+1}}, \, \theta\ge \beta, \alpha>0, \beta>0
$$

What is the Bayes estimator of $\theta$? Do the prior and posterior belong to the same family of distributions (i.e., conjugate prior)?

(2) What does this estimator converge to as $n\to \infty$?

---

My work is as follows.

The prior distribution:
$$
\pi(\theta)=\frac{\alpha\beta^\alpha}{\theta^{\alpha+1}}I[\theta\ge \beta]
$$
and the likelihood function is
$$
f(X|\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i;\theta)=\frac{1}{\theta^n}I[0\le X_{(1)}\le X_{(n)}\le \theta]
$$
where $X_{(1)}\le \dots X_{(n)}$.

Then the posterior distribution is
$$
\pi(\theta|X)\approx \pi(\theta)L(X|\theta)=\frac{\alpha\beta^\alpha}{\theta^{n+\alpha+1}}I[0\le X_{(1)}\le X_{(n)}\le \theta]I[\theta\ge \beta]
$$

So for $\beta\ge X_{(n)}$, $\pi(\theta|X)\approx \frac{\alpha\beta^\alpha}{\theta^{n+\alpha+1}}I[\theta\ge \beta]$.

For $\beta<X_{(n)}$, $\pi(\theta|X)\approx \frac{\alpha\beta^\alpha}{\theta^{n+\alpha+1}}I[\theta\ge X_{(n)}]$.

But I have no idea about the distribution of $\theta|X$? Does it mean $\theta|X\sim Pareto(n+\alpha,\beta)$?

---

For the Bayes estimator,
$$
\hat{\theta}=E[\theta|X]=\int_R \theta \pi(\theta|x)dx
$$

As $\beta\ge X_{(n)}$,
$$
\hat{\theta}=E[\theta|X]=\int_\beta^\infty \theta \frac{(n+\alpha)\beta^{n+\alpha}}{\theta^{n+\alpha+1}}d\theta=\frac{(n+\alpha)\beta}{n+\alpha-1}
$$

As $\beta< X_{(n)}$, the pdf of $\theta|X$ is
$$
g(\theta|x)=\frac{(n+\alpha)(X_{(n)})^{n+\alpha}}{\theta^{n+\alpha+1}}I[\theta\ge X_{(n)}],
$$
then
$$
\hat{\theta}=E[\theta|X]=\frac{(n+\alpha)X_{(n)}}{n+\alpha-1}
$$

It seems that this result is not right because the Bayes estimator should be weighted of the prior mean ($E[\theta]=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha-1}$) and sample mean $\bar{X}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pareto is indeed conjugate to the uniform, see e.g. [Aside from the exponential family, where else can conjugate priors come from?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192554/aside-from-the-exponential-family-where-else-can-conjugate-priors-come-from/192675#192675).

The posterior mean looks right, see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution (in Wikipedia's notation, $\alpha>1$ is guaranteed as the present $\alpha$ is positive and the sample size $n\geq1$).

The result that the posterior mean is a weighted average of prior mean and MLE (which the sample mean is not, though, so that I am not sure why to expect that in the first place?) is restricted to certain parametrizations in exponential families (and the uniform is not a member). See e.g. [Can the posterior mean always be expressed as a weighted sum of the maximum likelihood estimate and the prior mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/498250/can-the-posterior-mean-always-be-expressed-as-a-weighted-sum-of-the-maximum-like) or [How does Prior Variance Affect Discrepancy between MLE and Posterior Expectation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486602/how-does-prior-variance-affect-discrepancy-between-mle-and-posterior-expectation).

We have that the maximum $X_{(n)}$ is consistent for $\theta$. This follows from, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2905482/expectation-and-variance-of-y-maxx-1-ldots-x-n-where-x-is-uniformly-dis (slightly adapting the argument from a uniform on $[0,1]$ to one on $[0,\theta]$; essentially, work with cdf $y/\theta$ on $[0,\theta]$ instead of cdf $y$ on $[0,1]$) and noting that $E(X_{(n)})\to\theta$ and $V(X_{(n)})\to0$, so mean square convergence which implies consistency.

Also, $(n+\alpha)/(n+\alpha−1)\to1$ the posterior mean will tend to either the true $\theta$ or, when $\beta\geq X_{(n)}$, to $\beta$. [One could additionally consider the variance of the Pareto posterior, which is $\mathcal{O}(n^{-2})$.]

Asymptotically, the latter only seems possible when $\beta$ is larger than the true $\theta$ in view of consistency of $X_{(n)}$ for $\theta$. In that case, the support of the prior does not include the true parameter so that the posterior mean cannot concentrate on the true value.

Here is a little plot with posteriors for different $n$ and one prior choice for $\beta$ smaller (solid) and one larger than the true upper bound of the uniform (vertical black bar). We notice how the posterior concentrates around either the sample maximum or $\beta$.

[image]

```
library(EnvStats)

theta <- 1
beta.low <- 0.8
beta.high <- 1.03
alpha <- 0.5

n <- c(10, 20, 30, 50)
x <- runif(n[4], 0, theta)

x.n <- sapply(n, function(i) max(x[1:i]))

alpha.n <- alpha + n
beta.nlow <- max(x.n, beta.low)
beta.nhigh <- max(x.n, beta.high)

theta.ax <- seq(0.95, 1.1, by=.0001)
plot(theta.ax, dpareto(theta.ax, beta.nlow, alpha.n[4]), type="l", lwd=2, col="deeppink4")
lines(theta.ax, dpareto(theta.ax, beta.nlow, alpha.n[3]), type="l", lwd=2, col="lightblue")
lines(theta.ax, dpareto(theta.ax, beta.nlow, alpha.n[2]), type="l", lwd=2, col="orange")
lines(theta.ax, dpareto(theta.ax, beta.nlow, alpha.n[1]), type="l", lwd=2, col="chartreuse")

lines(theta.ax, dpareto(theta.ax, beta.nhigh, alpha.n[4]), type="l", lwd=2, col="deeppink4", lty=2)
lines(theta.ax, dpareto(theta.ax, beta.nhigh, alpha.n[3]), type="l", lwd=2, col="lightblue", lty=2)
lines(theta.ax, dpareto(theta.ax, beta.nhigh, alpha.n[2]), type="l", lwd=2, col="orange", lty=2)
lines(theta.ax, dpareto(theta.ax, beta.nhigh, alpha.n[1]), type="l", lwd=2, col="chartreuse", lty=2)

abline(v=theta, lwd=4)
```

*Quibbles*: The posterior mean is only "the" Bayes estimator when you working with the squared error loss function.

Also, you could omit the lower indicator in the likelihood function since you *know* that all $X_i$ are nonnegative.

To indicate that the posterior is proportional to some kernel of a distribution, it is more common to use $\propto$ than $\approx$.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask why "Since the maximum $X_{(n)}$
 is consistent for $\theta$"?

Comment: Sure, I was a bit fast there, please see the edit.